# Combining jQuery selectors with 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having some trouble combining these two specific selectors, whereas I don't have the same issue with simple selectors.

This is what I usually use (combining .btn and .toggle):

```
$(".btn, .toggle").removeClass("on");
```

These are the two I cannot combine (trying to combine this and the #toggle + id attr):

```
$(this).addClass("on");
$("#toggle" + $(this).attr("id")).addClass("on");
```

To be clear, I'm trying to combine the above 2 selectors as they do the same thing (adding the class), here's the full code.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    $(".btn, .toggle").removeClass("on"); 
    $(this).addClass("on");
    $("#toggle" + $(this).attr("id")).addClass("on");
})
```

And what I'm trying, that doesn't work:

```
$(this, "#toggle" + $(this).attr("id")).addClass("on");
```

Is there a special way I need to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add elements to a collection:

```
$(this).add($("#toggle" + $(this).attr("id"))).addClass("on");
```

Or in a more readable way:

```
var toggleId = "#toggle" + $(this).attr("id");
var $toggleElem = $(toggleId);
$toggleElem.add(this).addClass('on');
```

Please note that in this example, the variable `$toggleElem` itself is not modified, it still contains only one element.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I was after, I will look into add a little more. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a `, #`

```
 $("#toggle, #" + $(this).attr("id")).addClass("on");
 //        ^ change here
```

Comment: That selector works fine, I'm trying to combine both selectors that I listed in the 2nd example, eg:

$(this, "#toggle" + $(this).attr("id")).addClass("on");

Comment: @Phill this will do `'#toggle, #someid'`.

Comment: Edited my original post with full example, I think there was a misunderstanding, unless I'm reading the responses incorrectly

Comment: That selects an element with id `toggle` and elements with tag name whatever the id of the element is, unless the id starts with a `#` or `.` which is highly unlikely